# How can i calculate height plus pixels in LESS

Tags: html, css, less

How can I calculate 100vh plus ... pixels in LESS?
I know how to do it when I have to calculate 100vh minus ... pixels with escaping the calc arguments like this:

```
calc(~'100vh - 10px')
```

This compiles to:

```
calc(100vh - 10px);
```

But when I calculate with plus

```
calc(~'100vh + 10px')
```

This compiles to:

```
calc(100vh+10px)
```

How can I add an space before and after the plus?

Comment: What is the compiler version and are you using any other compressors/optimizers etc? It compiles with the spaces in the latest compiler at http://less2css.org

Comment: I'm using version 2.4.0. And yes i'm using an CSS compiler too that will remove all spaces, but when I calculate minus ... pixels it's not a problem.

Comment: The reference Less compiler (any version) actually can't remove any spaces if you write it as ~'100vh + 10px' (even with `-x` option which was deprecated), just because it does not make any modifications to escaped values by their definition. So yes, whatever tool does this in your build chain it's not Less.

Comment: For those with the same question, that are also using LESS with a CSS minifier; This is my solution: height: ~'calc(100vh - -10px)';